# Synchronized method in thread subclass

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a class that extends thread and in whose run() another method is called. I want that method to be synchronized, is it possible for a method that is defined in a thread subclass to be synchronized?

Comment: What happens when you try? Why would this method be different from any other method?

Comment: You normally should not subclass `Thread`, but instead have a class implement `Runnable` and create a normal `Thread` using `new Thread(yourRunnable)`.

Answer (score 2):

`synchronized` is not part of the method signature. It is simply a shorthand for wrapping the method body in a block synchronized on either `this` or `TheEnclosingClass.class`.

This has a couple of consequences for methods in subclasses:

- You can make an overriding method synchronized, even if the overridden method isn't.
- If you *don't* make the overriding method synchronized, it doesn't "inherit" the synchronized-ness from the overridden method. You have to do it explicitly if you want it to be synchronized too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with that. The reason is that every method is called within a thread anyhow. So in a thread's method call stack, somewhere a synchronized method or block **may** get executed. So, this method of yours is no different from any other that may be called in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: There's nothing special about the `Thread` class, and there's nothing special about any class that you define that `extends Thread`. Sure, the `Thread` class has methods that do things that other class methods don't do, but the same could be said of the `String` class or the `HashMap` class or any class that's worth writing.

Sure, `Thread` is part of the Java standard library, and your class isn't.  Sure, `Thread` belongs to the `java.lang` package, which actually *is* a little bit more special than other packages. But, even despite all of that...

...It's *just* a class.

---

P.S., Other answers here all contain good advice. Read 'em!